# How to clear form from apllied css class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form which uses jquery validation so every valid and invalid fields it applies some css classes. at the end I have `submit` and `cancel` buttons. Problem is cancel button. when I click on cancel all applied css and text in `<span>` tag has to be removed . SO here what I tried but its not working correctly

first is my generated `<span>` tag,

```
<span class="status" id="status">
<font color="red">Id in use</font>
</span>
```

Here is jquery script for cancel button,

```
$('#clearform').on('click', function () {
$("#create_teacher").validate().resetForm();
var myString = $("#tIdTextbox").html();
alert(myString);
var element = $(myString);
element.find("font").each(function(index) {
    var text = "";
    $(this).replaceWith(text);
});
$("#create_teacher").removeClass('success');
$("#create_teacher").removeClass('error');
$("#create_teacher").removeClass('valid');
});
```

can anyone help me in this please

Comment: Do want to remove whole span tag or only text inside span tag ?

Comment: could you please provide the full html code? because you are calling id's in the jquery which are not in the html code.

Comment: show fiddle of you question

Comment: @BhushankumarLilapara only text

Comment: @d1m5n Here `#create_teacher` is a form id and `#clearform` is cancel button id, `#tIdTextbox` is textbox id where `span` is there next to it.

Comment: You can try to select each input manually, or simple use the css classes to select. $('#create_teacher .error').removeClass('error'); With this all error classes will disappear

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery validator plugin then please try to replace

```
$("#create_teacher").validate().resetForm();
```

with

```
var validator = $("#create_teacher").validate();
validator.resetForm()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#clearform').on('click', function () {
    $("#create_teacher").validate().resetForm();

    //To remove all the css you have apply in span
    $("#create_teacher").find("span").removeAttr('class');

    //To remove all the text you have apply in span
    $("#create_teacher").find("span").empty();
});
```

Comment: Thank you , it solved but problem is I have some other span tags that will also bocome empty. I want only this tag to be empty.

Comment: and how to remove other applied css on html elements.

Comment: For that share your whole html structure. In that specify that which span tag's text you want to preserve and also which other elements css you want to remove..

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this.

$('span.error,span.valid,span.success').removeClass('success').removeClass('valid').removeClass('success').text('');